# In Godot (gdscript) It has an error parsing a JSON file and it expects a comma somewhere, "call: Error parsing JSON at line 2: Expected ','

Tags: json, dialog, gdscript

heres my code:
extends CanvasLayer

```
export(String, FILE, "*.json") var d_file

var dialogue = []

func _ready():
start()

func start():
dialogue = load_dialogue()

$NinePatchRect/Name.text = dialogue[0]['name']
$NinePatchRect/Chat.text = dialogue[0]['text']

func load_dialogue():
    var file = File.new()
    if file.file_exists(d_file):
        file.open(d_file, file.READ)
                return parse_json(file.get_as_text())
```

and the video I'm following is this one: https://youtu.be/7CCofjq_dHM

I tried many thing explained in the video but nothing works. I'm expecting it to parse a JSON file with text inside and make dialogue for a NPC.

Comment: For the error you mention, the problem is in the file. How does the file contents look like?

Comment: [
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "OH! A survivor! I'm not the only one here!"}
 {"name": "you", "text": "uh, yeah! I am."}
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "ah yes, I forgot. I'm a blacksmith. Not a NPC or anything..."}
 {"name": "you", "text": "..."}
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "Well, anyway, I'm here so you can get better guns, kill zombos to get gun parts and come back here!"}
 {"name": "you", "text": "Ok."}
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "anyway, off you go, bye!"}
 {"name": "GAME", "text": "(you were kicked out.)"}
]

Comment: file:///C:/Users/oof19/OneDrive/Desktop/json/Blacksmith%20chat%231.json

Comment: You can edit your question to add information.

Answer (score 0):

So, on this Json data:

```
[ {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "OH! A survivor! I'm not the only one here!"} {"name": "you", "text": "uh, yeah! I am."} {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "ah yes, I forgot. I'm a blacksmith. Not a NPC or anything..."} {"name": "you", "text": "..."} {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "Well, anyway, I'm here so you can get better guns, kill zombos to get gun parts and come back here!"} {"name": "you", "text": "Ok."} {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "anyway, off you go, bye!"} {"name": "GAME", "text": "(you were kicked out.)"} ]
```

Let me fix spacing a bit…

```
[
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "OH! A survivor! I'm not the only one here!"}
 {"name": "you", "text": "uh, yeah! I am."}
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "ah yes, I forgot. I'm a blacksmith. Not a NPC or anything..."}
 {"name": "you", "text": "..."}
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "Well, anyway, I'm here so you can get better guns, kill zombos to get gun parts and come back here!"}
 {"name": "you", "text": "Ok."}
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "anyway, off you go, bye!"}
 {"name": "GAME", "text": "(you were kicked out.)"}
]
```

You can an array, which is delimited by `[` and `]`. And it has objects, which are delimited by `{` and `}`... But arrays should be comma separated. So it should look like this:

```
[
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "OH! A survivor! I'm not the only one here!"},
 {"name": "you", "text": "uh, yeah! I am."},
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "ah yes, I forgot. I'm a blacksmith. Not a NPC or anything..."},
 {"name": "you", "text": "..."},
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "Well, anyway, I'm here so you can get better guns, kill zombos to get gun parts and come back here!"},
 {"name": "you", "text": "Ok."},
 {"name": "Blacksmith", "text": "anyway, off you go, bye!"},
 {"name": "GAME", "text": "(you were kicked out.)"}
]
```

There the elements of the array (i.e. the objects) have commas (",") between them.